# UITapGestureRecogniser not working with UiTableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am working with UITapGestureRecognizer for doubleTap on a UITableViewCell.

So I added the gesture in this way in CellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
  UITapGestureRecognizer *m_doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTap:)];
    m_doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;


    [tableCell addGestureRecognizer:rightSwipeGestureRecogniser];
    [tableCell addGestureRecognizer:m_doubleTap];
```

But

```
- (void)doubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecogniser
{
}
```

is not getting Instead this is called

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  { 
  }

So i tried this..

```
 m_doubleTap.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
   m_doubleTap.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
```

Now it works and but didSelectRowAtIndexPath functions gets very slow.

So How to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting

`[cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];`

Hope this solves your problem.

or try implementing the following method and return `nil`

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```